# Need to code to skip one line of query based on previous value

Tags: sql, db2

IN the below code, we have a problem when the row is a Royalty row, but doesn't have LC then the lack of LC will wipe out the amount displayed from this part:

```
CASE WHEN lctype='RO' THEN ROUND(SUM(totalland.olrqty),2) ELSE 0  
                  END NAME(roytotal) COLHDG("Royalties") LEN(11,2),
```

How would I code that, if LCTYPE = "RO" then don't check the next line if its = 'LC'  ? As what happens here is this column totalland/olrqty) will get zero'd when LC but if previous was RO we dont want to zero.

```
SELECT   olsrom, olorno, olline, olprdc, oldesc,                             
            olrqty COLHDG("Qty Rec") LEN(11,0), WDATA(lctype),                
            SUM(olamou.olrqty) LEN(11,2) NAME(unit) COLHDG("Unit Price"),     
            CASE WHEN lctype='RO' THEN ROUND(SUM(totalland.olrqty),2) ELSE 0  
              END NAME(roytotal) COLHDG("Royalties") LEN(11,2),               
            CASE WHEN lctype='LC' THEN ROUND(SUM(totalland.olrqty),2) ELSE 0  
              END NAME(lctotal) COLHDG("Add-on Cost") LEN(11,2),              
            (roytotal+lctotal+unit) COLHDG("Landed Cost") NAME(totallc)       
              LEN(11,2)
```

Comment: You can't do this in a select statement, maybe with common table expressions, but your best with out a lot of learning is probably to use a stored procedure  that enters the table into a temporary copy and saves the previous lines lctype within the same row then selecting off that table will allow your case to work.

Comment: What I wanted was the CTE. Can't we code like, when there is an RO dont do else 0 on the next part?

Comment: Sample data and results would help.

Comment: Your query seems to be cut off. We see no `FROM` or `JOIN` clauses or the complete nested `CASE WHEN` statement which is integral to your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the LAG function to check a value in the previous row.

EDIT (if ParFait is right):

Just add...

```
OR lctype = 'RO'
```

...to that next line:

```
CASE WHEN lctype='LC' OR lctype = 'RO'
THEN ROUND(SUM(totalland.olrqty),2)
ELSE 0
END NAME(lctotal) COLHDG("Add-on Cost") LEN(11,2),
```

Comment: OP is not referring to previous row but previous line in query.

Comment: In both CASE WHEN's, lctype is presumably exactly the same piece of data - yes? Then my answer will do the trick. Please correct me if I'm wrong - I can take it. :P